# I keep getting the error: object of type 'NoneType' has no len() in python, what's wrong with the code?

Tags: python, list, function

Ok so this is the code I'm working with that keeps giving me this error:

```
def median(lst):
    slst = lst.sort()
    if len(slst) == 1:
        median = lst[0]

    else:
        index = len(slst) - 1

        if len(slst) % 2 != 0:
            median_index = index / 2
            median = slst[median_index]

        else:
            upper_val_index = len(slst) / 2
            lower_val_index = upper_val_index + 1
            upper_val = slst[upper_val_index]
            lower_val = slst[lower_val_index]
            average = (lower_val + upper_val) / 2.0
            median = average

    return median
```

I already tried using the sorted() function on the list but that does not work either. I'm just starting out with python so not so complicated answers are appreciated :) thanks!

Comment: What line raises that exception? Show us the traceback.

Comment: How exactly does `sorted()` not work?  What happened when you tried it?

Comment: @KirkStrauser I'm learning python on codecademy.com which does not show me the traceback.

Comment: @iCodez using sorted() results in the same error, so I was merely saying that that is not the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Methods that modify existing lists, like `sort`, do not return anything. So your code sets `slst` to None.

Instead, just call the method without assigning:

```
def median(lst):
    lst.sort()
    if len(slst) == 1:
        median = lst[0]
```

Alternatively, you can use `lst = sorted(lst)`, which *does* return a new list, but that is unnecessary.

Comment: Creating a new list might be desirable.  Having the function mutate its input just to find the median value is somewhat of a "nasty surprise".

Comment: There is still an error in the code because whenever i call it with the list [4, 5, 5, 4] it returns 5.0 while it should return 4.5. Why is it not sorting properly?

Comment: @OmarMerhabi: the function is sorting just fine.  Your logic is wrong; add `print(lower_val_index, upper_val_index)` to see your mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the .sort() method does the sorting on the list itself by changing the order of the elements in the list and it doesnot returns anything, So you have 2 choices:

```
"""
1. Either use the .sort() method as lst.sort() # This will change the original list.
2. Use the sorted() method which returns a new list. and you can easily assign it to new variable.
"""
def median(lst):
    slst = sorted(lst)
    if len(slst) == 1:
        median = lst[0]

    else:
        index = len(slst) - 1

        if len(slst) % 2 != 0:
            median_index = index / 2
            median = slst[median_index]

        else:
            upper_val_index = len(slst) / 2
            lower_val_index = upper_val_index + 1
            upper_val = slst[upper_val_index]
            lower_val = slst[lower_val_index]
            average = (lower_val + upper_val) / 2.0
            median = average

    return median
```

Here is the slight modification of the code for making it to work desirably, Kindly study the differences and try to learn from the mistakes, There are sure some more good ways to achieve the same but this required the minimal change .

```
def median(lst):
    slst = sorted(lst)
    if len(slst) == 1:
        median = lst[0]

    else:
        index = len(slst)

        if len(slst) % 2 != 0:
            median_index = index / 2
            median = slst[median_index]

        else:
            upper_val_index = len(slst) / 2
            lower_val_index = upper_val_index - 1
            upper_val = slst[upper_val_index]
            lower_val = slst[lower_val_index]
            average = (lower_val + upper_val) / 2.0
            median = average

    return median




print median([4,5,5,4])
>>> 4.5

print median([4,5,5,5,4])
>>> 5
```

Comment: There's no point simply fixing the code without explaining what is wrong.

Comment: sorted creates a new list so your code is not the same

Comment: so when I used your code, I don't get an error but I get a wrong answer. When I called the function with the list [4, 5, 5, 4]. It returned 5.0, meaning that it did not sort the list properly.

Comment: Man read your question first, you have inquired about the `NoneType` issue  with `len()` function , I tried to resolve that but I cannot assure if you have implied correct logic thereafter , try fixing the logic by yourself.